# How to parse childs of an html element?

Tags: javascript

I have this in my html:

```
<table id="my_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>my content</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any simple way to parse the table tree and get to the `<td>` element (node)?

Comment: Get the `<td>` for what and where? Do you want to apply CSS to it?

Comment: I's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by `parse the table`?

Comment: Read Selectors CSS selectors and jQuery Selectors on Read dom traversing in Javascript.

Comment: @JakubMichálek: I mean by (parse the table tree) get the td element and apply css to it

Comment: If you want to apply css just use css selector in your css file (e.g. #my_table td { background-color: red; })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comment you can do something like below:

```
 var tbl = document.getElementById("my_table"); 
var cell  = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td")
cell[0].style.color = "red";
cell[0].style.border = "1px solid black";
cell[0].style.padding = "20px";
cell[0].style.background = "#c0c0c0";
cell[0].style.fontSize = "50px";
```

http://jsbin.com/aDiQuNU/2/edit?html,output

Comment: I have 3 tables in the same page, so i want to apply css just to the td of table with id my_table

Comment: I have updated my code to work for table with id my_table

Answer (score 1):

CSS selector (use in css file - simplest way to apply css style):

```
#my_table td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

In case you use jQuery (following code will return collection of elements matching to the query in quotes):

```
$("#my_table td")
```

If you want to iterate through tds:

```
$("#my_table td").each(function(k, td) {
   $(td).css("css property", "css value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<table>` elements have a row property that holds all `<tr>` elements and `<tr>` elements have a cells property that holds all `<td>` elements.

```
var table = document.getElementById("my_table");
var tr, td, r, c;

// Iterate the rows
for (r = 0; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
    tr = table.rows[r];

    // Iterate the cells
    for (c = 0; c < tr.cells.length; c++) {
        td = tr.cells[c];
        /*
         * r = current row number
         * c = current cell number
         * tr = current row
         * td = current cell
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

it is much easy to parse html using simpleHTMLDOM class written in PHP.
check its document there are few examples over there

please follow link below

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

njoy scrapping :)